# Acronis True Image not seeing my primary active Windows Server 2003 partition

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, partition, acronis, alignment

Let me just say that the partition boots well and the are no bad sectors on the physical media.

I am running RAID5 on ICH9R.  I used dispart of Server 2008 to create an aligned partition.  Then installed Server 2003 Ent R2 SP2 on the new partition, formatting it from Server 2003 setup sequence.

In Acronis True Image Bootable version 8353 I notice that it can't see the partition's NTFS file system.  Already opened a ticket for them.

I am trying to create a key-less Sysprep image of my server to protect against future failures as well as to help in making new servers with exactly the same software.  Acronis backup works in Windows, but then I cannot back it up after Sysprep was executed.

RAW backup takes entirely too long (2.5 hours), and it won't let me resize the partition upon restore.

Was wondering if you could recommend something else that I might try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got it!

Had to create bootable media on that particular computer, instead of relying on the one from Acronis website.  ISO size increased from 35MB to close to 100MB, but it enabled proper detection of the partition.